# how to highlight selected html content as summary c#,jquery,javascript,ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

this is just an example

e.g: let said i selected word "this" and clicks "Highlight" button, then the word "this" will be highlighted, by how to do that?

*updated--so basically "this is just an example" is html contents, what i want to do is highlight any words by clicks a button, and then copy the highlighted words as my summary

for example i selected "this" by mouse, than i clicks "Highlight" button, then "this" will be highlighted, further more when i clicks another button "copy", all highlighted word will be copy to another page as summary

anyway==the sample that i provided is just an normal content, cant really help in highlight, and what i want to know is how to highlight by button clicks =(

Comment: Could you use http://jsfiddle.net to elaborate on your question?  It's a little ambiguous.

Comment: i found 1 thing,thing that i typed all is missing= =hold ya

Comment: Really nice tool there Jesse, hadn't seen that one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there's a jQuery framework that does this:

- [highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)